# docker push says image does not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, containers

I have a docker image, essentially a node application with mongodb database.

The docker image shows up when I try

```
docker images
```

but when I try to push it in dockerhub, it says image does not exist

```
azim ~/Documents/nodejsWorkSpace/articleapp $  (master) docker push azimshaik/articleapp_app
The push refers to repository [docker.io/azimshaik/articleapp_app]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: azimshaik/articleapp_app

azim ~/Documents/nodejsWorkSpace/articleapp $  (master) docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
articleapp_app            latest              042f8aaf3b57        About an hour ago   708MB
azimshaik/nginx-website   latest              573bfe563763        23 hours ago        109MB
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

[docker image is available in the list locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbWFV.png)

Any leads on what I am missing here ? Appreciate your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to explicitly tag your image to include your repository name.

Add the correct tag with the following command:

`$ docker tag articleapp_app azimshaik/articleapp_app`

Then you should be able to push the image with:

`$ docker push azimshaik/articleapp_app`

Hope this helps